# PrimeNG table not applying any style

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable

Basic styling is not being applied. Tried multiple ways to apply styles. Added primeng-min.css, omega etc, did not help.

```
<p-table></p-table>
```

Data loads in tabular format without styling.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Please add some code spinet from your controller and html.